# Line breaks in String resource using Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html

I have a String resource I need to display in a TextView.

```
Step 1: Request a mobile fuel card from the card issuer&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;Step 2: Scan the QR code in the activation mail with the app or click on the activate button if you open the mail on your smartphone.&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;Step 3: Enter a username&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;Step 4: SMS verification. Press on the link in the text message to continue&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;Step 5: Choose a personal PIN code</string>
```

I set it using textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

The problem is that the linebreaks that are included in the String resource are not shown.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to add it as HTML? If you use \n in your string as linebreak it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `</br>` for `\n`.

```
        textView.setText((Html.fromHtml(text)).toString().replaceAll("\\</br.*?>","\\\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between `br` and `/` in your HTML text. 
Also try using `<br />` rather than `</ br>`.

So your html string will be like this:

```
Step 1: Request a mobile fuel card from the card issuer &lt;/ br &gt; &lt;/ br&gt; Step 2:  ...AND SO ON...
```

Mind the spaces between ending `&lt;` and starting `&gt;` as well

Once you make above changes, perform these steps:

```
String textHtml = String.format(getString(R.string.YOUR_HTML_STRING), "RANDOM");
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(textHtml);
textViewHeml.setText(html);
```